# Visual Flow loop variable is not incrementing or progressing

Tags: flow, loop

I have set up a Salesforce Visual Flow that has a fast lookup to a custom object that returns 3 rows. This goes to a SObject collection variable. The fast lookup works. I then follow with a loop step to loop through the collection. However the loop variable (which is an Sobject var of the same record type as the object) picks up the first record off the collection and does the subsequent steps but does not pick the next item off the list.

[image]

Have also tried this which loops through the collection but never ends, just keeps looping.

[image]

Here is the fast lookup followed by the loop
[image]

[image]

Comment: In your test screen, do you check the values of the LoopVar1 variable?

Comment: Yes, i display some of then in the Test screen. in any case i now have it working. Seems that when its called from its proper place & not just run in place it doesn't go into an endless loop.